numpy.distutils was deprecated. How to install libtiff?
I have a series of tiff images and need to read them using the following command:
from libtiff import TIFF
tif = TIFF.open(tiff_image, mode = "r")

I cannot use Image.open as I'd like to get object attribute in the next step (tif.iter_images).
Given this context, I do need to install libtiff but it fails due to dependency with numpy.distutils which has been deprecated. My Python version is 3.12.7.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Please provide the full error message you're seeing, not a vague description of it.

Consider using tifffile from https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/

@MarkSetchell I added your comment in my answer :)

numpy.distutils is removed in python 3.12. Here is the migration advice:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/distutils_status_migration.html#distutils-status-migration

To install libtiff you can use python 3.11 or 3.10
libtiff's latest version was Released: Dec 21, 2017
https://pypi.org/project/libtiff/#history

Alternatively, you can use tifffile as @Mark commented
tifffile is supported for python 3.10, 3.11, 3.12, 3.13.
https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/

Thank you for taking the time and responding my question. tifffile worked for me. However, I couldn't make libtiff work on Python 3.11.
